# How to always have json output show up nicely formatted using jq without appending the jq command

Tags: json, api, command-line-interface, jq

I just installed jq on Ubuntu 18.04 and It is really nicely formatted when making curl calls. I am wondering if there is a way to always have my terminal(s) output JSON data nicely formatted without having to append the `| jq .` command to the end of it? I am familiar with setting up aliases in my `.zshrc` file but there is no single command I would use this for so not sure how to make this happen.

Dummy command I ran

```
curl -X GET localhost:3000/products | jq .
```

I want the jq command to always be in effect when returning json to from the CLI.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

While I won't go so far as to say this *cannot* be done, not only am I not aware of any straightforward way of doing so, I think it would be extremely challenging to do at all for the following reasons:

1. It's hard to reliable identify that a command is outputting JSON. Many things might look like JSON but not be intended to be JSON. A command might output something that looks like JSON in large part but that isn't entirely JSON.
2. It's impossible to know if a long-running command is outputting valid JSON until it has finished. This gives a dilemma of what to do in the interim - wait for it to finish, potentially indefinitely (especially if it's waiting for your input!) or find some way to roll-back the output if it turns out we guessed wrong.
3. It's hard to predict up-front if a command is going to return JSON. As in your example, you can't tell what the remote server is going to return from a curl command.
4. It's unclear what's the "right" thing to do for non-trivial commands, such as invoking shell functions or pipelines or applying redirections, or for programs such as text editors that use advanced control codes for redrawing the screen.

For these reasons, I think if this is possible it would require quite an advanced shell that captures the output of all commands the user executes, analyses and formats that output continuously, and has the capability to roll-back and reformat (or unformat) the output if it realises the output is incompatible with its method of display. I think that would be pretty interesting to see but I'm not aware of such a shell.

Comment: Seems like it wouldn’t be worth it. I just created the short alias to be jq only and ill just append it when I need it etc... thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

You could start with a simple script, e.g.

```sh
$ cat curljq
#!/bin/bash
curl "$@" | jq .
```

```sh
$ chmod +x curljq
$ ./curljq -Ss -H "Accept: application/json" https://reqbin.com/echo/get/json
{
  "success": "true"
}
```

Comment: Is this a bash script?

Comment: Fixed. It is now :-)